# AWS Environment Variables - IDE

Tags: command-line, ventura

I use the IntelliJ IDE for my daily tasks. I set up my AWS environment variables, by executing a script. If I wish to use a plugin built into the IDE to query AWS K8S it will fail as it expects the AWS environment variables to be set OS-wide.

The AWS environment-specific variables are only set in the context of the terminal running in the IDE. If I do `env` in a separate terminal, the environment variables for AWS differ and match the default values I set via apple-script example `do shell script "launchctl setenv AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 12345"`.

What is the best approach here to set the AWS environment variables at the OS level, which then can be read by the built-in plugin as well as the IDE CLI session?

Answer (score 0):

Including the following statements provided a solution I could use with MacOS Ventura and IntelliJ.

#### Unset global AWS environment variables

```
launchctl unsetenv AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
launchctl unsetenv AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
launchctl unsetenv AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
launchctl unsetenv AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

#### Set global AWS environment variables

```
launchctl setenv AWS_DEFAULT_REGION $REGION
launchctl setenv AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
launchctl setenv AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
launchctl setenv AWS_SESSION_TOKEN $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Comment: How will launchd know what $REGION is?

Comment: @mmmmmm it will never see the variable, it’s value will get substituted by the shell before launchctl is executed. But maybe the OP just wanted to say „put Region here“.